# RTC to Git migration failing

Tags: git, github, rational-team-concert

how to migrate RTC projects to GIT-bitbucket? I downloaded the project from https://github.com/rtcTo/rtc2gitcli & without modifying any file was able to execute the "scm migrate-to-git" but seems like 0 changest, 0 baseline & took 34 seconds to complete. I am not sure where do I give the git/bitbucket repository information? my code is quite big & it will certainly not complete in 34 seconds. Any idea where am i supposed to give the git repo details & where will i check if it is run success!!

using RTC 6.0.4 & SCM cli
exported the jar file from eclipse project but did not make any changes the downloaded code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure where do I give the git/bitbucket repository information?

You are (first) supposed to:

- create and load an RTC repository workspace: "SOURCE_WORKSPACE"
- a local Git repository (git init myNewRepo): "TARGET_WORKSPACE"

Then you can provide source and destination with:

```
scm migrate-to-git -r <uri> -u <username> -P <password> \
  -m <migration.properties> <SOURCE_WORKSPACE> <TARGET_WORKSPACE>
```

(`uri` being the URI of the RTC server)